# componentInstance.setState undefined in 0.11.0

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following component in a file called `DashboardPosition.js`:

```
var DashboardPosition = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            items: []
        };
    },
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div className="well well-sm dashboard-item">
                This component has {this.state.items.length} items
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

I then render this with no problems in my page like so:

```
var dashboardPosition = <DashboardPosition />;
React.renderComponent(dashboardPosition, document.querySelector("#position"));
```

But when I try the following:

```
var dashboardPosition = <DashboardPosition />;

React.renderComponent(dashboardPosition, document.querySelector("#position"));

dashboardPosition.setState({
    items: [{name: "AMD"}, {name: "LIQ"}, {name: "ELEC"}]
});
```

I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
    dashboardPosition.setState
```

This seems to be only occurring in `v0.11.0`. I've tried it in `v0.10.0` and it works fine. Possible bug or have I missed something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was a change that started in 0.10.0 by giving you a warning in the development build, and in 0.11.0 is now a "breaking change".

When you make an instance of a component, what's returned is a *descriptor*, which is just whatever react needs to render that component.  Previously to 0.10.0 this happened to be the actual virtual dom nodes, which lead to a lot of antipatterns and removed potential from react being able to optimize certain things.  You can no longer do anything with the returned values except:

- return them from a render function
- use the `cloneWithProps` add on to make an updated copy

If you need to setState on a DashboardPosition component, you need to do it from within DashboardPosition.

If it doesn't make sense to do from within DashboardPosition, you should be passing `items` as a prop, e.g. `<DashboardPosition items={items} />`, and using `this.props.items` instead of `this.state.items`.

Comment: In a case like this you can just do `React.renderComponent(<DashboardPosition items={newItems} />, target)` when you want to update it.  Just try not to do the document.querySelector each time.